# What is the curl command to call Node js Express api

Tags: node.js, api, express, curl

I want to call and pass value to express api using curl cmd.

and I want access passed value in express api

```
app.post("/myapi",(req,res)=>{
  console.log('come her')
  console.log(req.ip)
(*) here I want print passed value from the curl cmd
  res.send('done')
})
```

Comment: You can access the request body using `req.body`

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have an endpoint named `/endpoint` that allows for a request body, request parameters, and query strings.

In Express, our endpoint could look something like this:

```js
app.post('/endpoint/:name', (req, res) => {
    // Log the request body
    console.log(req.body);
    
    // Log the request parameter(s)
    console.log(req.params);
    
    // Log the request query string(s)
    console.log(req.query);
    
    // Send a response to the request
    return res.send('Hello, World!');
});
```

What we are doing here is individually logging out each part of the request once it comes in. The most commonly accessed parts of a request inside of Express would be the request `body`, `params` and the `query` properties. For a full list of properties available within the request object, please see the official [Express API Reference](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#req).

Now, to call our endpoint via cURL, we can run the following command:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:3000/endpoint/john?name=john' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "name": "john"
}'
```

This will send a request to the `/endpoint` endpoint, simultaneously sending the same data via the request body, parameters, and query strings.

The output in your console should look something like this:

```
{ name: 'john' }
{ name: 'john' }
{ name: 'john' }
```

As you can see, the request body, parameters, and query strings contain the same value, even though they were sent in completely different formats.

This provides a ton of flexibility, as it is unlikely that you will always need all of the properties available on the request object at one time and it is advised to choose those that best fit the needs of your individual project functionality instead.